# Where statement after order by statement

Tags: sql

I want to ask after groping by AVG the values > at 8, Something like this

```
SELECT avg(students_subject.nota) as avg, students.name
FROM students_subject
left JOIN studentsON students.id=students_subject.id_alumno
GROUP BY students_subject.id_student 
where avg > 8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **HAVING** when comparing with GROUP BY. **WHERE** could not be used with an  aggregate function. Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT avg(students_subject.nota) as avg, students.name
FROM students_subject
left JOIN studentsON students.id=students_subject.id_alumno
GROUP BY students_subject.id_student 
HAVING avg > 8;
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `having` clause for conditions that refer to aggregation functions:

```
SELECT avg(students_subject.nota) as avg, students.name
FROM students_subject
left JOIN students ON students.id=students_subject.id_alumno
GROUP BY students_subject.id_student 
having avg(students_subject.nota)> 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference site [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
HAVING condition
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

Example

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5;
```